# Selinux policy - not working

Tags: selinux

each day I have error messages because of clam AV scan - it is a selinux problem - I already have a selinux module created - but the error is not solved. could anyone have a look at it? I think the module should allow write, read access to the files for clamscan?

selinux error:

```
Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:antivirus_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
Target Context                system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
Target Objects                sess_604rv54bntl70jig0bjf1lfja4 [ file ]
Source                        clamscan
Source Path                   /usr/bin/clamscan
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          myserver.com
Source RPM Packages           clamav-0.99.1-1.el7.x86_64
Target RPM Packages           
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-60.el7_2.3.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Host Name                     myserver.com
Platform                      Linux myserver.com
                          3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu May 12
                          11:03:55 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   94
First Seen                    2016-05-15 03:56:15 CEST
Last Seen                     2016-05-17 03:45:49 CEST
Local ID                      68ee97b8-2226-4481-97be-1eeccbb0e566

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1463449549.453:49931): avc:  denied  { read } for pid=9274 comm="clamscan" name="sess_604rv54bntl70jig0bjf1lfja4" dev="dm-1" ino=67123073 scontext=system_u:system_r:antivirus_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 tclass=file


type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1463449549.453:49931): arch=x86_64 syscall=open success=no exit=EACCES a0=7f16e0aee540 a1=0 a2=0 a3=fffffffffffffb85 items=0 ppid=9135 pid=9274 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=5454 comm=clamscan exe=/usr/bin/clamscan subj=system_u:system_r:antivirus_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)

Hash: clamscan,antivirus_t,httpd_sys_rw_content_t,file,read
```

and here the policy:

```
module clamscanlocal 1.0;

require {
type antivirus_t;
type httpd_sys_rw_content_t;
type usr_t;
class dir search;
class file { write read getattr append };
}

#============= antivirus_t ==============

#!!!! This avc can be allowed using the boolean 'antivirus_can_scan_system'
allow antivirus_t httpd_sys_rw_content_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc can be allowed using the boolean 'antivirus_can_scan_system'
allow antivirus_t httpd_sys_rw_content_t:file getattr;
allow antivirus_t usr_t:file { write read append };
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just enable the boolean as stated by the audit2allow output instead of creating a policy?

`setsebool -P antivirus_can_scan_system=on`

Good SELinux Tutorials: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials

Answer (score 0):

modify policy rule in your file (second last line), additional read permission added here.

> allow antivirus_t httpd_sys_rw_content_t:file {read getattr};

also if possible change your enforcing mode to permissive mode,
Ref: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_selinux/changing-selinux-states-and-modes_using-selinux

If your error solved, no audit logs found than change enforcing mode to enforce mode.